# crashed when delete a string that copied from a string class by memcpy

Tags: c++

I new a string class and then copied it to another string class by memcpy,
it crashed when i delete it from another string class.
Could anybody help to explain it?
Thanks

```cpp
union Data {
    bool _bool;
    int16_t _int16;
    int32_t _int32;
    int64_t _int64;
    uint16_t _uint16;
    uint32_t _uint32;
    uint64_t _uint64;
    float _float;
    double _double;
    char s[sizeof(std::string)];
} ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Data d1;
    new(d1.s) std::string("123");

    Data d2;
    memcpy(d2.s, d1.s, sizeof(d1.s));

    void *p2 = d2.s;
    auto delStr2 = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(p2);

    void *p1 = d1.s;
    auto delStr1 = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(p1);

    delStr2->~basic_string();  //crashed

}
```

Comment: Why use `sizeof(std::string)` as size for the array? Also you are doing some crazy stuff here. There are easier ways to copy a string. Then you cast a char[] to string*. In the end you are invoking the destructor of std::string on a char[]. And why do you manually call the destructor? Is this just an experiment of how to cause undefined behaviour? Or do you have any real problem you try to solve here?

Comment: I personally do not get what you try achieve here. Could you explain your thoughts?

Comment: You can't use `memcpy()` to make copies of non-POD types, especially ones that have constructors and destructors, like `std::string` does. Don't use `memcpy()` for types that are not [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) (ie `std::is_trivially_copyable<type>::value` is false)

Comment: The call of `memcpy()` gives undefined behaviour.   Using `memcpy()` on memory that is occupied by a non-trivial C++ class (e.g. with non-trivial constructor and destructor) gives undefined behaviour).   One possible symptom of that is destruction of the affected object or objects subsequently failing.    More generally, once undefined behaviour occurs in a program, the behaviour of any other subsequently executed code is also undefined (i.e. the standard specifies no constraints on what happens).

Comment: change to delStr1->~basic_string(); , it works.
You said can not do it, but haven't explained why.

Comment: _"Could anybody help to explain it?"_  You got lucky.  It crashed.  If you were unlucky, it wouldn't have crashed and you may have mistakenly assumed it worked.

Comment: @Peter subsequently *and previously* executed code. Optimizers are allowed to make time-travelling UB :)

Comment: @Peter
can you explain more clearly why can not call its destructor?

Comment: @flying010101 - No need.   When behaviour is undefined, any behaviour you get depends on how the compiler does things.   Quite different behaviour can occur with different compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` is a not a [trivially copyable type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), copying it with `memcpy` results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: trivially copyable type means a class can be copied safely(deeply copy).
```
memcpy(d2.s, d1.s, sizeof(d1.s)); 
```
although it is a shadow copy,  i think it's safe to call destructor only one time.

Comment: @flying010101 - trivially copyable means (among other things) that the type has a copy constructor that is either trivial or deleted, and a trivial non-deleted destructor.  `std::basic_string` (of which `std::string` is a specialisation) has a non-trivial copy constructor and a non-trivial destructor so is not a trivial type.